# Difference between "People" and "Users" OU in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

In the default Active Directory, there is `ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com` and, beneath that, `ou=People,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com`. **What is the distinction between the intended purposes of the two?**

It seems like maybe `ou=Users` would contain service accounts, whereas `ou=People` is specifically for real people, but I cannot find any documentation of this. For that matter, is there documentation anywhere on the rationale behind this layout?

Comment: People who aren't users can, for example, be contacts, whose contact details (email address etc) are stored in AD.  People could be members of a distribution group in AD, but obviously not of a security group.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to the administrators of the domain to decide. There is no standard. There is some documentation about how to organize it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/reviewing-ou-design-concepts

This describes the default containers in Active Directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/delegating-administration-of-default-containers-and-ous

Out of the box, `Users` is actually a container, not an OU (`CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com` - notice the `CN=`). The only difference is that only OUs can have group policies applied to them, but containers cannot.

If yours is actually an OU, that means that someone has already changed that.

To my knowledge (but maybe I'm wrong) there is also no `People` OU out of the box, so that must have been added by someone.